# How do I reverse the order in which error bars appear using geom_errorbar() in R?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have the following example plot:

```
test <- data.frame("Factor" = as.factor(c("O", "C", "A")), 
                       b = c(0.18, .34, .65, -.13, .38, .26), 
                       lower95 = c(-.1, .09, .34, -.52, .10, -.02), 
                       upper95 = c(.48, .58, .98, .26, .67, .56), 
                       group = factor(c("Experiment 1","Experiment 2")))

test$Factor <- factor(test$Factor, as.character(test$Factor))
test$group <- factor(test$group, as.character(test$group))

ggplot(test, aes(Factor, b, colour = group)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower95, ymax = upper95), 
            size = 1,
            width = .5, 
            position = 'dodge') +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  ylim(-1.25, 1.25) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw() + 
  ggtitle("Title") +
  theme(
axis.text=element_text(size = 20), 
axis.title=element_text(size = 18),
plot.title = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold"),
axis.text.y=element_text(size = 12)
  )
```

As you'll see, the error bars appear in the reverse order (from top to bottom) as they do in the legend. I would like Experiment 1 error bars to appear above Experiment 2 error bars.

I have tried

```
ggplot(test, aes(Factor, b, colour = forcats::fct_rev(groups)
```

But this reverses the order of the *group labels* in the legend, not the order of the colours in the legend–which is what would work. I have also tried reversing the order in which I enter them in the data frame and this does not solve the problem.

I would appreciate some help!

Comment: In addition to your `fct_rev` code you can reverse the legend order via `+ guides(color = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE) )`.  That way the legend and plot visually match and `Experiment 1` comes first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Re-factoring will change the order of the plot, but, as you saw, also changes the order of the legend.  In addition to reversing the levels of `group`, you can reverse the order the legend is displayed with the `reverse` argument in `guide_legend`.

```
ggplot(test, aes(Factor, b, colour = forcats::fct_rev(group))) +
     geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower95, ymax = upper95), 
                   size = 1,
                   width = .5, 
                   position = 'dodge') +
     geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
     ylim(-1.25, 1.25) +
     coord_flip() +
     theme_bw() + 
     ggtitle("Title") +
     theme(
          axis.text=element_text(size = 20), 
          axis.title=element_text(size = 18),
          plot.title = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold"),
          axis.text.y=element_text(size = 12)
     ) +
     guides(color = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE) )
```

[image]

If you are using `scale_color_discrete` or `scale_color_manual` to control other scale elements like the legend name, you can use `guide_legend` there instead of via `guides`.

```
+
scale_color_discrete(name = "Experiment", guide = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
test$Factor <- factor(test$Factor, levels = rev(levels(test$Factor)));
test$group <- factor(test$group, levels = rev(levels(test$group)));

ggplot(test, aes(Factor, b, colour = group)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower95, ymax = upper95),
            size = 1,
            width = .5,
            position = 'dodge') +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  ylim(-1.25, 1.25) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw() +
  ggtitle("Title") +
  theme(
axis.text=element_text(size = 20),
axis.title=element_text(size = 18),
plot.title = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold"),
axis.text.y=element_text(size = 12)
  )
```

[image]

I'm not entirely clear on whether you want to reverse the ordering of `test$Factor` as well; just (un)comment the corresponding line depending on what you're after.

Comment: This seems to still have the Experiment 2 bars [above the Experiment 1 bars](https://imgur.com/a/h8Uy1). 

What I would like is for the red bars in that image (i.e., those corresponding to Experiment 1) to appear above the green bars.

Comment: But experiment 1 errorbars (in green) *are* above the errorbars of experiment 2 (in red), see the attached plot. Do you want to swap the *colours* instead?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I'd hoped for Experiment 1 to come before Experiment 2 both in terms of the order of the error bars, and the order in which they are listed in the legend.